# Browsersync is running but does not refresh the page

Tags: docker, magento, gruntjs, browser-sync

I have MacOS + installed Docker container by Mark Shust (https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento) + installed browsersync on the host.

Magento has ".less" files in the folder: app/design/frontend. I set a folder as a current one in the cli. And run this command from the host:

```
 browser-sync start --host "domain.test" --proxy "https://domain.test" --files "**/*.less" --https
```

I get this output:

```
[Browsersync] Proxying: https://domain.test
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: https://localhost:3000
    External: https://domain.test:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://localhost:3002
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

I can open https://domain.test and it works properly. http://localhost:3002 shows that there are no current connections. However, the output in the cli infoms: "[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers..."

if i change less, i still can find changes on the website but only after a manual reload.

The documentation mentions grunt configuration and there are some recipes as an example. I tried to use standard magento's file but it does not help. It looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
'use strict';

grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        files: 'app/design/**/*.less',
        tasks: ['less']
    },
    browserSync: {
        dev: {
            bsFiles: {
                src : [
                    'app/design/**/*.css'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                watchTask: true,
                server: './'
            }
        }
    }
});

// load npm tasks
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

// define default task
grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync', 'watch']);

var _ = require('underscore'),
    path = require('path'),
    filesRouter = require('./dev/tools/grunt/tools/files-router'),
    configDir = './dev/tools/grunt/configs',
    tasks = grunt.file.expand('./dev/tools/grunt/tasks/*'),
    themes;

filesRouter.set('themes', 'dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes');
themes = filesRouter.get('themes');

tasks = _.map(tasks, function (task) {
    return task.replace('.js', '');
});
tasks.push('time-grunt');
tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    require(task)(grunt);
});

require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    configPath: path.join(__dirname, configDir),
    init: true,
    jitGrunt: {
        staticMappings: {
            usebanner: 'grunt-banner'
        }
    }
});

_.each({
    /**
     * Assembling tasks.
     * ToDo: define default tasks.
     */
    default: function () {
        grunt.log.subhead('I\'m default task and at the moment I\'m empty, sorry :/');
    },

    /**
     * Production preparation task.
     */
    prod: function (component) {
        var tasks = [
            'less',
            'cssmin',
            'usebanner'
        ].map(function (task) {
            return task + ':' + component;
        });

        if (typeof component === 'undefined') {
            grunt.log.subhead('Tip: Please make sure that u specify prod subtask. By default prod task do nothing');
        } else {
            grunt.task.run(tasks);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Refresh themes.
     */
    refresh: function () {
        var tasks = [
            'clean',
            'exec:all'
        ];
        _.each(themes, function (theme, name) {
            tasks.push('less:' + name);
        });
        grunt.task.run(tasks);
    },

    /**
     * Documentation
     */
    documentation: [
        'replace:documentation',
        'less:documentation',
        'styledocco:documentation',
        'usebanner:documentationCss',
        'usebanner:documentationLess',
        'usebanner:documentationHtml',
        'clean:var',
        'clean:pub'
    ],

    'legacy-build': [
        'mage-minify:legacy'
    ],

    spec: function (theme) {
        var runner = require('./dev/tests/js/jasmine/spec_runner');

        runner.init(grunt, { theme: theme });

        grunt.task.run(runner.getTasks());
    }
}, function (task, name) {
    grunt.registerTask(name, task);
});};
```

Should it work without gruntjs running? And why the page reload is not triggered?

PS: I did not place this question into https://magento.stackexchange.com/ cause i believe it's a general problem and not related to Magento.

Comment: So, i found that it's possible to run it without gruntjs. Here is a good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXSLwq7c-UE. I tried it with local environment and it works. But it still does not work with docker...

Comment: I found either another info that it might work on local host: https://docs.hyva.io/hyva-themes/working-with-tailwindcss/using-browser-sync.html but it still does not work for me